# Is there a way to customize the ticks in ggplot2 themes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As you know, there are many themes in ggplot2 such as theme_economist, theme_minimal, theme_tufte, etc.

For instance, I would like to add this code to my visualisation:

```
theme_economist(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

But I am getting the "unused argument" error because I can add this argument to only theme function.

You can simply use this code:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=5) + theme_economist()
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not ```ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=5) + theme_economist() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) ```

Comment: Or `your_theme <- function(...) theme_economist() + theme(...)`. Then do `your_plot + your_theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have two options.

**Option 1**

Create a new function that adds the elements of the theme to the original function, then use that function in `ggplot()` sequence. Here, `theme_new` is the new theme with the tick labels at 90 degrees. Note that when you use `theme_new` you omit the parentheses (i.e., `theme_new` and not `theme_new()`).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

df <- data.frame(
    x = rnorm(1000, 500, 100),
    y = rnorm(1000, 500, 100)
)

theme_new <- theme_economist() + theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme_new
```

**Option 2:**

Create your own theme by copying the `theme_economist()` definition in the `ggthemes` library and replace the code with the design elements that you want. If you want to view the definition, you can view it [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggthemes/versions/3.5.0/source).